# prevent windows 10 mobile from locking

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have finally upgraded my windows 8 app to windows 10 app. Unfortunately some of the features are not working in windows 10. One of the features I am looking is preventing automatic lock screen while my application is running.

In windows phone 8 I am using below code to prevent auto locking of windows phone, however, in windows 10, I didn't find this feature.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

What is the alternate of the above in windows 10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might use the new [DisplayRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx) class

Pretty simple to use :

```
displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive();
//Do your always on stuff
displayRequest.RequestRelease();
```