# C# uwp application prevent idle mode

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

Windows Phone 8 had the ability for your app to **prevent the phone from going to the lock screen**:
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled ;

**Anybody know what the equivalent is for Universal Window Platform?**

Comment: The answer to the linked question should work. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238140/prevent-windows-10-mobile-from-locking)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive();
```

But be aware of the fact that you are just **requesting** the screen to stay active. This can not prevent the user from locking the screen by himself manually.

Comment: Excellent! It works! Vielen Dank!! Jetzt kann ich mein App benutzen.